# How to select specific filenames nested within several folders?

Tags: python, python-2.7, iteration, glob, os.walk

I have a working folder on "C:\Users\userName\Desktop\test" where my python test script is located. My idea was to import directory from another drive ("D:\mydir\mytests\Projects") to my current working directory:

```
import os
from os import getcwd
curdir=os.getcwd()
path = os.chdir(os.path.join(curdir,"D:\mydir\mytests\Projects"))
```

Under "Projects" directory there are several folders which my contain also subfolders (but not every). I am trieng to make some kind of a generic code that will iterate over "Projects" directory access every folder or subfolder if it exist and find specific files with ".proj" extension. Found files (".proj") should than be writen out in a form of a list (maybe) so i can run each of them one by one with a for loop. I tried to write down some code but not successfully. Any suggestion will be appreciated a lot.

```
proj_list = []
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(path):
    for f in files:
        dest_dir = glob.glob('*.proj')
        fullpath = os.path.join(dirpath, f.dest_dir)
        proj_list.append(fullpath)


def activate_approval(dialog):
    dialog.activate_button('yes')


class OpenAllProjectsFromListAndRun(script.TestScript):

    def test_run (self):

        for project in fullpath:

                with self.handle_dialog(activate_yes):
                    self.open_project(project)


                    '''nothing in particular'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = OpenAllProjectsFromListAndRun()
    test.run()
```

PS: I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: What is `f.dest_dir` supposed to be? Because I can guarantee that it's not that.

Comment: Well i am not much into python but i hoped it would generate all ".proj" files as i described in text. This code neads modification it is only a sketch.